# Insert voice instructions to android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, voice

I'm developing an application in android studio for the first time (written in Java).
Since it is gonna be an application for children, one feature I want to have, is a character who will guide them on what to do - for example:

> Press here to open the box

I want it to be vocal and also textual since not all the kids know how to read yet.
I've searched for a way to insert audio into the application for each instruction I want to have, but I'm not sure it is the "smartest" way to do it.
Also, I'm not sure how to do that automatically without the need to press start/resume/stop for operating the audio file.
Which way would be the correct way to do this? and how exactly can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use text-to-speech engine build inside android.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech

https://www.javatpoint.com/android-texttospeech-example